# How can I sort an array of key : objects based on object values

Tags: javascript, sorting

I have my data like this

[image]

I am trying to sort it like this

```
$initialArrayBTC.sort(function (a, b) {
    return b.q - a.q //Trying to sort is on the base of "q" in descending order
});
```

But this does not seem to work although I looked through many stackoverflow answers. Can anyone help me what might be the issue?

**EDIT** This is my all data inside the object

**SAMPLE CODE**

```js
var $initialArrayBTC = [];
$initialArrayBTC['A'] = {
  q: "3598"
};
$initialArrayBTC['B'] = {
  q: "123"
};
$initialArrayBTC['C'] = {
  q: "9999"
};
console.log($initialArrayBTC);

$initialArrayBTC.sort(function(a, b) {
  return b.q - a.q //Trying to sort is on the base of "q" in descending order
});

console.log($initialArrayBTC);
```

[image]

Comment: Is the result of b.q - a.q always either 1, 0 or -1 ? That's what the function has to return.

Comment: the sort function returns a sorted array as far as I remember. Try `$initialArrayBTC = $initialArrayBTC.sort(....`

Comment: @Dennisvdh I am just trying it to sort it on the basis of q

Comment: Is "q" a field containing a number or string? You should parse de value if you have a string and expecting to sort by the value number.

Comment: no need to convert a stringified number. the minus operator casts both operands to number, if not already a number.

Comment: do you get any error while sorting?

Comment: No i don't get any error whole sorting either @NinaScholz

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/8na74sb1/ it's working here, and I don't see any reason why it wouldn't in your case.

Comment: try to debug inside of your sort function what you getting value after `b.q - a.q`

Comment: @Jeto you dont have String as keys. This is not an indexed array.

Comment: @AliZia they do have strings as keys, "q" is like a string, you can try adding double quotes but that won't change anything. What do you mean?

Comment: @Jeto but my structure is different from your array. Please verify.

Comment: @AliZia can you please do a jsfiddle with your structure, please? I am with Jeto and I've seen it working.

Comment: @AliZia It's not. It's an array of objects, mine just doesn't have the other keys (because they're meaningless in your case). But yeah, just post a sample (don't have to use jsfiddle, you can edit your OP too).

Comment: I am just seeing that the function inside the sort is not executing.

Comment: Yes, something is wrong with the structure of your variable, I am seeing that your array has size 0, thats why is not executing. If you do: $initialArrayBTC.length you can see that is "0"

Comment: you are trying to sort an object, not an array, even if you use an array with properties. the array sort works only for indexed (numbers as keys) properties.

Comment: That is not an array `$initialArrayBTC['A']` like you are thinking. Arrays in Javascript are indexed, JS doesn't have associative arrays.

Comment: So I can not sort them?

Comment: You cannot key them. Also, your question does not have anything to do with jQuery.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sorting JavaScript Object by property value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1069666/sorting-javascript-object-by-property-value)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could build a new object by creating the properties in the wanted order, but this may works only with not integer numbers (numbers as indices for array) as keys and maybe not in all browsers.

---

You could take an object and then the  keys of it, sort them and use the sorted keys for a sorted output.

```js
var $initialArrayBTC = {};

$initialArrayBTC['A'] = {q: "3598"};
$initialArrayBTC['B'] = {q: "123"};
$initialArrayBTC['C'] = {q: "9999"};

var keys = Object.keys($initialArrayBTC).sort(function (a, b) {
  return $initialArrayBTC[b].q - $initialArrayBTC[a].q;
});

keys.forEach(k => console.log($initialArrayBTC[k]));
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your initial instance is an object, as opposed to an array. You can grab its keys, sort the keys by values, then rebuild the object:

```js
const $initialArrayBTC = {
  A: {q: '3598'}, 
  B: {q: '123'},
  C: {q: '9999'}
};

const result = Object.keys($initialArrayBTC)
  .sort((key1, key2) => $initialArrayBTC[key2].q - $initialArrayBTC[key1].q)
  .map(key => ({[key]: $initialArrayBTC[key]}));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thankyou. I am now creating a new array without keys and sorting it with my existing function.